# How do I parse CSV file to MaxMind GeoIP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, geoip, maxmind

I have a CSV being generated every 2.5 hours with about 25 IP addresses.
I need to sort them according to their region (city,zip).
What would be the best way to implement this using JS/PHP?
ref: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/

Comment: What will you do with the results?

Comment: These results would be used as input for analytics.
p.s they would be used in an Excel document to create charts

Comment: Why using JS/PHP? You could create a console program for executing this task.